# Use PHP to check if directory files have changed

Tags: php, directory

In my WordPress site, I have a script that looks at a directory and uploads each image in that directory to a specific post. Right now, this is set to happen each time the user opens the post edit page. I need a way to check if the contents of the directory have changed. That way, I can set the script to not run if the contents of the directory have not changed. Is there a way to accomplish this in PHP?

Comment: You'd probably have to store the directory structure in a database to give you something to compare against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to make a hash of directory content, let's say concating the names of files (sorted) with some divider and making md5/sha1 hash. You'll need to store it in some way (in directory as text file or database).

On access you'll have to calculate actual hash of directory in the same way and compare it with the old (saved) one. Depending on result, you can take some actions...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the modification date of a file with filetime

http://php.net/manual/de/function.filemtime.php

A solution is to store the day of the last visit and look for younger files at the next visit.

Answer (score 0):

You can open every file in PHP and generate checksums with MD5, then save this with time() to text file in directory. Next time you can compare yours checksums and you will know if anthing has changed since last time.